# Is it possible Integrate nokia maps in my Android app?

Tags: android, here-api

I have to develop an Android app using the Here/Nokia maps here.com,

In Googlemap/Geocoder class from Android native ressources, I load a map, put how many markers I want, I can draw routes, iterate with the map, and so on.

Now my question is, Is this possible in Nokia maps?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

there are two 'android' offering for HERE amps which are available. The one used with Amazon: https://developer.amazon.com/sdk/maps.html

And the one used with Nokia X platform: http://developer.nokia.com/resources/library/nokia-x/here-maps.html

in general all of the functionality you are asking is available with both offerings. However you can not use the HERE maps in other than the specified environments, i.e. apps made for Nokia X using HERE maps, can not use the Maps parts in other platforms.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create a *Native* Android app, since the *Android SDK* is not yet available. From the [website](http://developer.here.com/web/guest/native-apis):

> HERE SDK for Android
>
> The HERE SDK for Android is an offer for OEM customers only.
>   Developers can access the HERE platform functionalities through OEMs
>   when they become available.

You can, however, create a web-based app using the [javaScript API](http://developer.here.com/web/guest/javascript-apis).

Answer (score 0):

Yes. There is an HERE maps SDK available for both android and ios , download it from https://developer.here.com .